# What's the fastest way to get all of the indices of false elements in a boolean array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, optimization, boolean

Let's say I have a boolean array with:
`{false, true, false, false, true, true, ...}`

What is the quickest way (most optimized) to get the indices of the (for instance) false elements? In this case `0 2 3`?

Comment: What size is the array? What data structure do you need the indices to be in? Why an array and not a [BitVector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx)?

Comment: Optimization is a buzzy kind of word -- in terms of what? Quickest performing? Quickest to write? Quickest to understand?

Comment: simple `for` loop will do the job well.

Comment: If this list was more than a few thousand elements long, it might be worth worrying about optimising it... otherwise clearer/most obviously correct is better I think. Which might just be the obvious loop anyway. :)

Comment: Call up intel, have them build you some custom hardware for that task. They can do that for you for less than a billion dollars.  (You're not going to get "the fastest" unless you have an unlimited budget. What are the constraints and how much are you willing to spend?)

Comment: @EricLippert Probably the best comment I've ever seen. You made my day, Sir.

Comment: Not getting the indexes is by far fastest way - it may be enough to just know that you can get them... Rewrite your code to avoid need for extra array...

Comment: @Oded, it is an array of about 600 elements. But I am using it to calculate primes, and if I want to get more primes I need a substantially larger array. I have not tried a BitVector yet. I will.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A for loop is likely the *fastest* way to do this:

```
List<int> indices = new List<int>();
for (int i=0;i < theArray.Length; ++i)
{
   if (theArray[i])
   {
       indices.Add(i);
   }
}
```

Note that you can probably gain a slight bit of speed at the cost of extra memory by preallocating the `List<int>`:

```
List<int> indices = new List<int>(theArray.Length);
```

This will avoid extra memory allocations.

Comment: Is this faster than @renan's bitmask?

Comment: Wow. Really easier than I thought. I'm new to big O notation but this is linear, right? There's only one loop (which is always just as big as we need it to be), and there is just an if statement in it.

Comment: @DavidWest Yes, this is O(N).

Answer (score 5):

For up to 32 elements:

```
int mask = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (!arr[i]) mask += 1 << i;
}
```

Mask will be a 32-bit mask where each bit is 1 if the element at that bit's index is false, and 0 if the element is true. It is another representation of the array, if you so wish to say, using four bytes instead of one byte per boolean value. For up to 64 elements you could use the `long` type instead. However, as far as I remember, with `int` you can turn an `enum` into a bitmask proper.

Total bytes involved: four for the mask, one for each element of the array, and four for the index in the loop. Total allocations done: two (if we don't count the allocation of the array).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that using a floating point power operation is going to be faster than using integer arithmetic...

Comment: 2**n is a fast operation... but the correct way to write it is `(1 << n)`, not `Math.Pow(2, n)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the fastest way, but it yields an IEnumerable of just the true indices.  It seems a little messy to me.  I wonder if it could be simplified?  A for loop is probably the best.  But for what it's worth:

```
var bools = new bool[] {true, false, true, true, false, false, true, false, true};
var falseIndices = bools.Select((b, i) => new { Index = i, Value = b })
                        .Where(o => !o.Value)
                        .Select(o => o.Index);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will never know what is the fastest of possible solutions, until you will have empirical evidence. You can use next code as a reference of computations speed comparison for LINQ and `for` loop approaches:

```
var r = new Random();
bool[] vals = new bool[100000000];

//initializing
for (int i = 0; i < vals.Length; i++)
{
    vals[i] = r.Next(2)==0;
}
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

//for loop benchmark
List<int> indices = new List<int>(vals.Length);
for(int i = 0; i < vals.Length; ++i)
{
    if(!vals[i])
        indices.Add(i);
}
Console.WriteLine ("for loop: {0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

watch.Restart();

//LINQ benchmark
List<int> falseIndices = vals.Where(flag => !flag)
                             .Select((flag, index) => index)
                             .ToList();

Console.WriteLine ("LINQ: {0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

prints something along:

```
for loop: 600 ms
LINQ: 2072 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way probably includes pinning the array using `fixed`. However the result code wouldn't be very readable.

You should ensure that "finding the indices of `false` elements" truely is the bottleneck in your application and finding "the fastest way" really improves it. Readability and maintainability are quite important aspects, too.

As others suggested, a simple for loop has good performance and is very readable. The Linq solutions wouldn't be much slower.

If the array contains alot of `true` and not alot of `false` you could consider using `Array.IndexOf()` for each `false` until you find no more occurrences. It might be faster than the per-element approach.

Comment: I actually doubt pinning the array would be faster than a for loop, as the main advantage to pinning is eliminating the bounds checks, but the JIT will do that for a simple for loop anyways...

Comment: If I understand correctly, `array[index]` also requires looking up the location of `array`, where accessing a pointer on a pinned array does not. Just for trying out I have noticed changing data in a `byte[]` sequentially is much faster using pointers than using the per-element approach. I don't know in this case, but I wouldn't recommend using it anyway :)

Comment: Changing data within an array (in most cases) is much slower because of the bounds checking on write.  Writing to an array within a for loop will eliminate the bounds checking optimizations from the JIT.  Reading from an array is typically not, so it'll be fast still.

Comment: @ReedCopsey The pinned solution is about 20% faster than a regular for-loop, for 50000 booleans where 50% were false. I just had to try :) The difference, as you mentioned, isn't as big as it is when changing data.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
    BlockingCollection<int> indexes = new BlockingCollection<int>(x.Length);
    Parallel.For(0, x.Length, i =>
    {
        if (x[i])
        {
            indexes.Add(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried it? on my machine it took 10 seconds for `100000000` bool values, while for loop took 500 ms

Answer (score 0):

I did some timings too, and it demonstrates that what people were saying is correct: 
Using pointers is not significantly faster than the simple loop.

I suspect the largest amount of time is taken up just populating the results list.

Here's the times I got from the following test program:

```
Unsafe took 00:00:06.6450271
Safe   took 00:00:06.7691818
```

Test code follows...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        void Run()
        {
            int size = 10000000;
            bool[] array = new bool[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
                array[i] = true;

            int count = 100;

            time(() => UnsafeCountSetFlags(array), "Unsafe", count);
            time(() => SafeCountSetFlags(array),   "Safe",   count);
        }

        void time(Action action, string title, int count)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                action();

            Console.WriteLine(title + " took " + sw.Elapsed);
        }

        List<int> UnsafeCountSetFlags(bool[] array)
        {
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (bool* parray = array)
                {
                    List<int> result = new List<int>();

                    for (bool* p = parray, end = parray + array.Length; p != end; ++p)
                        if (*p)
                            result.Add((int)(p-parray));

                    return result;
                }
            }
        }

        List<int> SafeCountSetFlags(bool[] array)
        {
            List<int> result = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
                if (array[i])
                    result.Add(i);

            return result;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().Run();
        }
    }
}
```